# Граф в виде связного списка

Tags: c++, классы, графы, списки

У меня есть пример реализации односвязного списка - структура и функция добавления в список элемента:

```
struct TNode {
    int value;
    TNode* pnext;
};

void add2list(TNode **pphead, int val) {
    TNode **pp = pphead, *pnew;
    while(*pp) {
        if(val < (*pp)->value)
            break;
        else
            pp = &((*pp)->pnext);
    }
    pnew = new TNode;
    pnew->value = val;
    pnew->pnext = *pp;
    *pp = pnew;
}
```

Хочу подобным образом представить граф в виде списка вершин и вложенных списков смежных вершин для каждой вершины:

```
struct Neighboor { // структура для списка смежных вершин
    int vertex_neighboor;
    Neighboor *pnext_neightboor;
};

struct Node {
    int vertex;
    Node *pnext;
    Neighboor **first; //указатель на первый элемент вложенного списка соседних вершин
};
```

Попытался подправить под это дело функцию add2list(), дописав еще одну, для заполнения списка смежностей. Прошу прощения за возможные нелепые ошибки, я пока новичок, только осваиваю язык.

```
void add2list(Neighboor **nnhead, int val) {
    Neighboor **rr = nnhead, *pnew;
    while (*rr) {
        if (val < (*rr)->vertex_neighboor)
            break;
        else
            rr = &((*rr)->pnext_neightboor);
    }
    pnew = new Neighboor;
    pnew->vertex_neighboor = val;
    pnew->pnext_neightboor = *rr;
    *rr = pnew;
}

void add2list(Node **pphead, int val, int neighoods[]) {
/*neighoods[] - массив смежных вершин*/
    Node **pp = pphead, *pnew;
    while (*pp) {
        if (val < (*pp)->vertex)
            break;
        else
            pp = &((*pp)->pnext);
    }
    pnew = new Node;
    pnew->vertex = val;
    pnew->pnext = *pp;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
/*В этом месте все падает. Двойка в цикле просто чтобы не заморачиваться пока, я передавал туда массив из двух элементов.*/
        add2list((pnew->first), neighoods[i]);
    }
    *pp = pnew;
}
```

Помогите найти ошибку или, если мой вариант совсем не дееспособен, подскажите способ реализовать задумку.

Выглядеть все должно в моем представлении как-то так:

```
 ________ **first _______  *next1 _______  *next2   *nextn
|vertex_1|  -->  |neigh- |  -->  |neigh- | -->  ...  -->  NULL
|________|       |boor_1 |       |boor_2 |
    | *pnext_1   |_______|       |_______|
    \/
 ________ **first _______  *next2 _______  *next2   *nextn
|vertex_2|  -->  |neigh- |  -->  |neigh- | -->  ...  -->  NULL
|________|       |boor_1 |       |boor_2 |
    | *pnext_2   |_______|       |_______|
    \/

    ...

    | *pnext_n
    \/
   NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, как минимум, вы не инициализируете `pnew->first`, в нем у вас какой-то мусор, когда вы пытаетесь добавлять к нему список. Обнулите его перед циклом.

Но это точно C? У вас в наличии две функции с одним и тем же именем

```
void add2list(Neighboor **nnhead, int val);
void add2list(Node **pphead, int val, int neighoods[]);
```

Такое отлично работает в C++, но не в C.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Это C++, не C.

Comment: Да, но у вас стоял тэг `c`, поэтому я и засомневался. Ну, если вопрос решен - помечайте ответ птичкой как принятый :)

Comment: Да, задача решена - нужно было илициализировать, кроме того в void add2list(Node, int, int*) в строчке где в цикле вызывается одноименная функция для элементов Neighboor, нужно было добавить амперсант - add2list(&(pnew->first), neighoods[i]) , и указателю *first лишнюю звездочку написал.